# API Username and Password

Tags: json, api, jwt, powerbi, base64

I am currently building a Power BI report, which is supposed to visualize some data that our company stores on the "Upland RightAnswers" platform. I am currently an Admin user in this platform, and I am trying to make a successful connection to the API to fetch the data into Power BI.

The API has a couple of required parameters. I am having problem with the Authorization parameter. The API is asking for a Base64 encoded Basic authentication in form of username:password. I understand that I need to write a header in this form:

> Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=

The string following the Basic argument is literally "username:password" encoded in Base64.

My problem is that I do not know in which form the username and password are supposed to be. Is this my work e-mail address and password that I use to log in to this platform? Or are there any "API" usernames and passwords that I could generate? I am asking this question, as I have worked with other platform, which automatically provide me with a complete JWT string that I could pass as a Bearer token, whereas this seems to be impossible on this platform. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!